# Find the area between $x^2 \sin(x/4)$ and $0$

Tags: calculus, integration

I have been at this for over an hour, can someone please help.

Let $F(a)$ be the area between the $x$-axis and the graph of $y=x^2\sin(x/4)$ between $x=0$ and $x=a$, for $a>0$ (consider the area to be negative if the graph lies below the axis).

$F(a) =$ ?

I thought $F(a) = 375.655$ but the webwork I am doing says that I am wrong.

I took the integral of x^2 sin(x/4) from 0 to 12.566371 and I got 375.655

Comment: If you would show us your calculation, we could look whether it's wrong or not and maybe where the error coudl be.

Comment: What have you done yet ? How did you compute F(a) ?

Comment: I took the integral of x^2 sin(x/4) from 0 to 12.566371 and I got 375.655

Comment: What is the integral ? What is 12.566371 and why this number ? What is 375.655 ?

Comment: 12.566371 is where the line of x^2 sin(x/4) intersects with 0.

Comment: Your number is an approximation of $4\pi$, you should always keep the exact values when doing computations. This being said, it's said nowhere in the question that $a$ represents this point, and you should integrate between $0$ and $a$, thus finding a value of $F(a)$ that is a function of $a$.

Comment: OKay, what are you getting for the numbers?

Comment: For which value of x does the line of  x^2 sin(x/4) intersects with 0 ? In any manner, you did not tell it in your post.

Answer (score 1):

It is very nice you be told that your answer is **not correct**.

$\sin(x/4)$ is zero if $x = 4 \pi$ (this is your 12.566371 which is just an **approximate** value). Then $a = 4 \pi$. If you plug this number in your integral (we are still waiting for it), the **exact** result is $64 (\pi^2 - 4)$, the **approximate** value of which being

$$375.65468166971895160540742399207367266\ldots$$

So, your value of $375.655$ is **wrong**.

Comment: @nbubis. Thanks for editing for the old man ! Cheers.